# How to change default login action

Tags: yii

I am newbie for Yii. I have created my separate login page in my controller. Here my question is "When

When session expires it will ask for re-login. and it will transfer to site/login page.

Instead of site/login I want to redirect it to xyz/login page. Where I have to change this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change in the main.php

```
array(
// ......
'components'=>array(
'user'=>array(
    'loginUrl'=>array('xyz/login'),
   ),
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 2):

in your config/**main.php**,

```
'urlManager' => array(

    ...

    'rules' => array(

        'xyz/login' => 'site/login', // Add this

        ...
```